# Issue with spanish characters in java string

Tags: java, string, internationalization

I have issue with spanish characters in java string. I have a content in a file and when i try to transform it to java object using InputStreamReader, the output of some string is "cÃ³mo" which should be "cómo". This is happening other spanish like

á = Ã¡
é = Ã©
í = Ã­
ó = Ã³
ú = Ãº

and more..

Could you please help me to convert it appropriate output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What encoding is the file in? Especially how is the ó represented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the character encoding in the constructor of `InputStreamReader`, like so:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i checked the transformation encoding is done using "UTF-8". So i thought if whether is there any way to convert string from "cÃ³mo" to "cómo" after the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Specify charset on your InputStreamReader - [`http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot. as you said the issue was with my java class. It is working now :)