# Spanish characters are displayed as Symbols when rendered using JSP

Tags: java, string, internationalization

Earlier i had a issue with spanish character encoding in Java encoding and for which i got solution in [Issue with spanish characters in java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857102/issue-with-spanish-characters-in-java-string).

Now when i want to display the contents in the JSP i am getting strange symbols in the page. When i had break point in JSP the contents are fine but in the page i see symbols in place of spanish characters

Example - "D�le" is displayed in place of "Déle".

I have added the page content in my JSPs

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" session="false" %>
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

is it charset `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1` for Latin?
Also, the browser, and the font all have to have the support for the charset and special characters used (For example: Verdana should work fine)
Is the browser rendering other spanish content (from www) properly?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 (aka ISO-Latin1) and Unicode encoded in UTF-8 both have the necessary characters, so it's your choice. The problem, then, is (1) encoding your text correctly in your chosen form, (2) telling the browser what that form is, and (3) using a font (as you point out) that has the glyphs you need.

Comment: Hi, I m using the charset UTF-8. the browser render other www spanish pages properly. if i change the character encoding to iso-8859-1 in browser then it displays fine. but that cannot be correct solution

Comment: `but that cannot be correct solution` - what are the charsets you are interested in? ISO-8859-1 has support for most of the western European characters.

Comment: We cannot expect the user would change the character encoding in his browser.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but as I said early all three should work hand-in-hand : browser, font, and your page.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following as well:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Meta tag is already available in the page, and i tried adding pageencoding but it is not working.